# Unit test for connection / C#

Tags: c#, nunit, webexception

Writing test for my application. Would like to test connection with exeption handling, for now I have created method which works and looks like :

```
        [Test]
        public void TestCreateConnection()
        {
            Connection testConnection = new Connection();
            connection.CreateConnection(correctURL, IDName + connection.ApiKey, connection.ContentType, connection.MediaType, connection.Get, false, "name");
            testConnection.CreateConnection(correctURL, IDName + connection.ApiKey, connection.ContentType, connection.MediaType, connection.Get, false, "name");
        }
```

In the finall version working on smth which will catch exception - `WebExeption`. Already have it in try / catch block inside my method which is about to create connection, it works ofc. But need it in my test as well. I was thinking it should looks like :

```
[Test]
        [ExpectedException(typeof(WebException))]
        public void TestCreateConnection()
        {
            Connection testConnection = new Connection();
            connection.CreateConnection(correctURL, IDName + connection.ApiKey, connection.ContentType, connection.MediaType, connection.Get, false, "name");

            testCconnection.CreateConnection(correctURL, IDName + connection.ApiKey, connection.ContentType, connection.MediaType, connection.Get, false, "name");
            Assert.Catch<WebException>(() => connection.CreateConnection("test", IDName + connection.ApiKey, connection.ContentType, connection.MediaType, connection.Get, false, "name"););
        }
```

Like we can see i changed first arg of the method which is URL address, it will couse the web exeption. How can i write it in correct way ?

Comment: In my opinion you should use Assert.Throws instead of ExpectedExceptionAttribute. Usage of Assert.Throws makes it more explicit where you expect exception. Your code should look like this: `Assert.Throws <WebException>(() => connection.CreateConnection(...)`. Furthermore NUnit 3.0 doesn't officially support ExpectedExceptionAttribute. At the end, you should have two independent unit tests - one for valid connection and one for invalid connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is anything wrong in your approach of testing the exception. I do suggest, however, that you split your test into two tests - one for the case where you get a valid connection, and one for the case where you get a bad connection.

```
    [Test]
    public void WhenCorrectUrlIsPassedConnectionCreatedSuccessfully()
    {
        Connection testConnection = new Connection();
        connection.CreateConnection(correctURL, IDName + connection.ApiKey, connection.ContentType, connection.MediaType, connection.Get, false, "name");
    }

    [Test]
    [ExpectedException(typeof(WebException))]
    public void WhenIncorrectUrlIsPassedThenWebExceptionIsThrown()
    {
        Connection connection = new Connection();
        Assert.Catch<WebException>(() => connection.CreateConnection("test", IDName + connection.ApiKey, connection.ContentType, connection.MediaType, connection.Get, false, "name"););
    }
```

This is without knowing the exact details of how you implemented the test connection. If you have some internal component in charge of creating the connection, and your code is a wrapper around it, then you should consider passing the internal component in as an Interface and mocking its behavior.